# Is it wrong to use void return type for each rule in recursive descendant parser?

Tags: algorithm, recursive-descent

Quoted from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser):

```
void term(void) {
    factor();
    while (sym == times || sym == slash) {
        getsym();
        factor();
    }
}

void expression(void) {
    if (sym == plus || sym == minus)
        getsym();
    term();
    while (sym == plus || sym == minus) {
        getsym();
        term();
    }
}
```

It's using `void` return type for each rule,

in that case, how can one know whether a specific branch fails or succeeds?

IMO, each rule should use a boolean return type to indicate whether this branch fails or succeeds.

Is this correct?

Comment: Tip: Don't say "What do you think?" or people will mark it as subjective. Instead say something like "Is this correct?"

Comment: @quasiverse,thx for the tip:)

Answer (score 0):

The example uses a model where a special "error" routine is responsible for reporting errors, but you could certainly formulate the parser as a function that returned "true" if the input represented a valid input and "false" otherwise. It's just two different styles.

Comment: And each entry of the rule should be chained by `&&`,say, `a() && b()`,not `a();b();`,right?

Comment: if you mean like prod = prod_part1 & prod_part2 & .., then yes.